# Is Hyperledger fabric free to use?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, private-network

So I know that the Hyperledger fabric is an opensource project and can be used but I still have some concerns about if it is still free to use when deployed in real life production projects.

I have researched about this and there are no clear defined answer to this as of what I saw. I just wanted to be legally safe to use it. So anyone who has used it could you let me know about this and also if I have to take some additional steps incase we are using it for production.

Also could you recommend some resources for setting up Hyperledger fabric other than the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The [LICENSE](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/LICENSE) document included in the Fabric source code repository is the [Apache 2.0 license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License). This is a permissive license that allows users to use the software for any purpose (including commercial use), to distribute it, to modify it, and to distribute modified versions of the software under the terms of the license, without concern for royalties.

In addition to the main [Fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/), which contains pretty clear steps for [installing Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/getting_started.html) and [deploying / running Fabric applications](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/getting_started_run_fabric.html), there is material from a [Fabric Full Stack Development Workshop](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide#readme) that might be helpful to get going with application development. This workshop does cover deployment on Kubernetes but I think you would need to look elsewhere for more detailed information on production deployment and operations.